# How to repair the System Restore Point Creating?

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I have a problem creating "System Restore Points" in Windows 10 21H2 (Build 19044.2075) with all latest updates.

If I try to **create a new System Restore Point**, I get an error message with the error code "**0x80042306**".

To solve this problem, I tried the following things:

- Login as Administrator
- Reboot Windows
- Stopping all other applications
- Creating a new Windows User and try to run the creation from there
- Checking the shadow storage with "vssadmin.exe list shadowstorage"
- Resize the shadow storage with "vssadmin.exe resize shadowstorage /for=c: /on=c: /maxsize=30%"
- My destination drive (C:) is formatted with NTFS and checked with "chkdsk.exe /f /r C:"
- Installing Windows on a different partition to check the hardware - that worked well
- Removing all group policies with "RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers" && RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicy"
- Only Windows Defender is installed as Anti Virus protection
- Starting Windows in the "Save Mode", but there is this feature not available
  "sfc.exe /scannow" doesn't report a problem
- The following services are running (checked with "services.msc")

  - Volume Shadow Copy
  - Task Scheduler
  - Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider Service
- The folder "System Volume Information" was deleted and rebuilt automatically
- "DISM.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth"

**Any Idea how I can fix this Problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Restore points are not a very robust thing.  Too many ways for them to break.

The best way to fix Restore Point creation is to delete all Restore Points, restart, check restore point creation properties (disk allotted) in Advanced System Properties.

Then let Restore Points rebuild as you install, uninstall things.

If the operating system is damaged and not allowing Restore Points to be created, then the most likely repair is a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link.

Start with the option to Keep Everything and then use the more aggressive options if need be.

A regular Repair Install will not fix a damaged user profile. The only practical repair for that is to reinstall Windows

Comment: There is not a general way to fix restore points - too many ways for them to break .  So you need to start again

Comment: I added steps to do a repair install to (likely) fix the issue

Comment: Repair and Keep Everything keeps apps and data and leaves you where you started with errors fixed. This is a reasonable way to try fixing your issue.  Indeed if standard repair install does not work, you are looking at reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The "AppleHFS" driver on my old MacBook Pro was the problem. This driver is a part of Apples BootCamp. After disabling it, all works fine again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).